# Why are 'The Bridge', 'The Tunnel' and 'The Pass' so similar?

Tags: the-bridge, comparison, the-tunnel, pagan-peak

I recently noticed, that the series *The Bridge (2011)*, *The Tunnel (2013)* and *Pagan Peak (2018)* begin very similar. Is that just a coincidence?

Similarities I noticed:

- the title, duh;
- a dead body is found on the border between two countries (literally half the body is in eg. germany, the other in austria);
- both countries send detectives, of which one is a woman, and one is a man;
- within the first couple of sentences, one side says "I'm in charge", and the other side agrees and leaves the scene without arguments;
- in *The Bridge* and *The Tunnel* both bodies happen to have belonged to politicians.

Comment: I think the titles only seem similar because the rest seems to be so.

Comment: the title is short, two worded, and describes where the murder and first scene takes place in

Comment: @nuuse note that the original titles aren't two-worded.

Comment: @nuuse Is there any source for "The Pass" as the title? IMDb only offers up "Pagan Peak" as the English title: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6905756/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt#akas

Comment: damn ur right.. sloppy translation without proper research by me- :c 
Although it just supported my question :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the Wikipedia page for *The Tunnel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tunnel_(TV_series)):

> *The Tunnel* (French: *Tunnel*) is a British-French crime drama television series **adapted from the 2011 Danish-Swedish crime series *The Bridge* (*Broen*, *Bron*)**.

---

From [the German Wikipedia page for The Pass](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Pass):

> Inspiriert wurden die Drehbuchautoren von der dänisch-schwedischen Serie *Die Brücke – Transit in den Tod*

Loosely translated:

> The writers were **inspired by the Danish-Swedish series *The Bridge***

Comment: In addition, there's The Bridge (2013), an American TV series from the same inspiration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridge_(2013_TV_series)

Comment: Also sounds similar to the Canadian action/comedy ["Bon Cop, Bad Cop"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0479647/).